# How to solve the "aps environment" right?

Tags: javascript, xcode, app-store, apple-push-notifications, aps

Use xcode to package the project and upload it to the App Store. Error prompt: Lack of push notification right - it seems that your app has registered with the Apple push notification service, but the right to sign the app does not include the "aps environment" right. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is delete the App Store distribution profile on your local machine, then re-download and install the distribution profile from the Provisioning Portal. This new one should contain the aps-environment key.

Answer (score 1):

The first project may lack Push Notification Cability
[image]

Second, click+Capability to select Background Modes in the pop-up box; Check Remote notification in Background Modes
Third, click+Capability to select Push Notification in the pop-up box to add
After successful addition, the project should have this: (Note that the content here does not need to be changed and Xcode will be automatically configured)
[image]